# pl sql function with nested if and multiple selects

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

I have a view. the view has a function that returns a text string of either "TRUE" or "FALSE" based on two criteria

The function looks at two tables.

Condition 1: The customer table contains a date field - if the system date is > the date field it should return false

Condition 2: The customer table links to a customer_detail table. there is sometimes a record in the detail table and sometimes not (so i added the outer join sytax to the query which doesn't really do anything because the additional criteria forces an inner join I believe). There can be multiple records in the customer_detail table for each record in the customer table. if there are multiple records in the detail table I need to look at the most recent record max(uniquefield). this table has a date field. if this field is not null the function should return false regardles of the first condition.

Here is what I have.  When I compile I get two errors:

> SQL statment ignored - at the first line of the first select statment

and

> Error(17,45): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist - on the subselect of the first select

```
create or replace FUNCTION "F_STATUS" (
N_UNIQUE IN NUMBER)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  V_TORF varchar2(20);
  D_ACTDATE date;
  D_STARTDATE date;
BEGIN
select b.startdate into D_STARTDATE
from customerdb.customer a, customerdb.customer_detail b
where a.uniquefield= b.uniquefield(+) and
b.uniquefield = N_UNIQUE and
b.uniquefield in 
  (select max(c.uniquefield) from customerdb.customer_detail c group by uniquefield);

if 
D_STARTDATE is not null
then
  V_TORF :='FALSE';
  RETURN(V_TORF);
else
  select expiredate into D_ACTDATE
  from customerdb.customer 
  where customerdb.customer.uniquefield = N_UNIQUE;
  IF 
      D_ACTDATE > SYSDATE 
      then
      V_TORF :='TRUE';
      RETURN(V_TORF);
   else
      v_TORF :='FALSE';
      RETURN(V_TORF);
   end if;
 end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your procedure seems to be unable to see the table `customerdb.customer_detail`. This is likely due to the fact that procedures are defined without any role enabled and you probably have a role with the SELECT ANY TABLE privilege. From the [security guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/authorization.htm#i1009241):

> The user who owns the procedure also must have privileges for schema objects referenced in the procedure body. To create a procedure, **you need to have been explicitly granted the necessary privileges** (system or object) **on all objects referenced by the procedure**. You cannot obtain the required privileges through roles. This includes the EXECUTE privilege for any procedures that are called inside the procedure being created.

To see if your procedure will be able to run a query, you can test with your user after having disabled all roles [with the following command](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551289900368934430):

```
set role none
```

In your case you probably need to be granted the SELECT privilege directly to your user:

```
GRANT SELECT ON customerdb.customer_detail TO <your_user>
```